# logical issues in seek bar increment decrement function. combination of 0.12 and 0.13

Tags: android

When incrementing I get this output:

```
0.12,0.25,0.38,0.50,0.62,0.75,0.88,1.00
```

But I want:

```
0.12,0.25,0.37,0.50,0.62,0.75,0.87,1.00
          ^^^^                ^^^^
```

When decrementing I get this output:

```
1.00,0.88,0.75,0.62,0.50,0.38,0.25,0,12,0.00,...
```

But I want:

```
1.00,0.87,0.75,0.62,0.50,0.37,0.25,0,12,0.00,...
     ^^^^                ^^^^
```

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView value;
double s = 0.12, c = 0, f1, v = 0.00;
int previous;
SeekBar seekbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sk1);
    seekbar.setMax(50);
    value = (Button) findViewById(R.id.value);


    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
            int p = progress;                   
            double f = progress;

            if (s == 0.12) {                    

                if (previous > p) {

                    float x = (float) (0.25 / 2 * 100) / 100;
                    f = v - x;
                    v = f;
                    value.setText("" + String.format("%.2f", (f1 + f)));
                } else if (previous < p) {

                    float x = (float) (0.25 / 2 * 100) / 100;
                    f = v + x;
                    v = f;
                    value.setText("" + String.format("%.2f", (f1 + f)));
                }
                previous = progress;
            }
        }
    });

}
```

**XML Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:text="0.00" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/sk1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why it matters (you'll still have one step of 0.12 and one of 0.13), but it's presumably rounding `0.375` to `0.38` etc.  You could try subtracting `0.001` from the value in the `format` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable feebback.I tried                                                i declare one more double variable likely named as r;                        else if (previous < p) { float x = (float) (0.25 / 2 * 100) / 100;
                    f = v + x;v = f;
                    r=f;                                                                       f=f-0.001;                                                                            value.setText("" + String.format("%.2f", (f1 + f)));  f=r;
                } while applying same logic in backward mode it was not work properly.